# How to check if an xml file is valid against xsd at runtime (not JUnit) using standard javax.xml.validation.Validator

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I know how to do this in a JUnit using :

```
String xsdPathname = getClass.getResource("/META-INF/xsd/my.xsd").getFile();
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(pathname));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(source);
```

but as far as I know, this is not usable when the xsd is packaged inside a jar.

Is there an other "schema" building method which would accept an "InputStream" instead of a "File" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SchemaFactory#newSchema(Source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema-javax.xml.transform.Source-), supplying a [StreamSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html). Thus, your code would look like

```
    InputStream xsdInputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/xsd/my.xsd");
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdInputStream));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(source);
```